# Not able to connect to Clear case server from eclipse SCM plugin

Tags: eclipse, version-control, eclipse-plugin

I tried installing SCM Adapter version 7.6.0.0 and version 7.0.2 with eclipse Version: 3.5.0, Version: 3.4.2 and Version: Juno Service Release 2 but no luck at all.

it is getting installed successfully but while connecting getting below error 
Select Details>> for more information.

```
Could not connect to Rational Clearcase.  Please ensure that the proper version
  of ClearCase is installed with the proper patches.  Consult the ClearCase SCM
  Adapter documentation for futher details.



  Provider name: IBM
  Plugin name: Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter
  Plugin ID: com.rational.clearcase
  Version: 7.6.0.v201105111445
```

and now getting very much confused, do i need to install complete Clear Case or CCRC will work, as I have CCRC installed on my desktop and it is working fine.

Please do provide your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of ClearCase do you have? There could be an issue with version SCM adapter 7.6 not being compatible with your CC version. That what it sounds like.

Your ClearCase installation should come with an update site to ClearTeam Explorer (CTE), which is a different Eclipse plugin that connects to ClearCase. Note though that you cannot have both CTE and SCM adapter installed at the same time, they are mutually exclusive.

There is also an [open source plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/) that works really well that might be worth checking out.

The advantage of having a Clearcase plugin in Eclipse is huge. You wont have to switch to desktop every time you want to edit a file. Instead the plugin will do that automatically for you. You also get a view listing all checked out files in your view, which helps alot.